# Submit multiple POST values in AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have a TON of AJAX requests that are submitted to my functions.php file using "actions".  Then in my functions.php file, I have many code blocks like the one below.

When I look at the developer tools, my functions.php file is being called many times as well (one for each AJAX POST).  I'm thinking about using Amazon S3 when I go live and they charge a fee based upon how many POST requests are sent.  The other concern I have is that I'm not sure that the way I've coded my functions.php file with all these blocks of code and associated AJAX requests is the best way to do it.  Could I put these code blocks in a function or class and somehow combine the AJAX POSTS request into only a few POST requests?

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action'] == 'delete_account')) {


        require("config.php");
        require("database.php");

        $deleteAccount = $_POST['account'];


        try {
            $results = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM account WHERE account_id_PK = ?");
            $results->bindValue(1, $deleteAccount);
            $results->execute();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "ERROR: Data could not be removed from the database. " . $e;
            exit;
        }
        echo $deleteAccount;
```

Can you do something like...

```
$.AJAX({
data: {action= "delete_account", ... action="add_account"...}
});
```

obviously the bit above is not my actual ajax code, just illustrating my question as best as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track yes. However you need to make a couple changes.

First off replace `=` with `:` in your Javascript object.

Then you need to make sure you are using unique key names. So either do `action1` and `action2`, or better yet create an array of actions like this:

```
data: { actions : ["delete_account", "add_account"] }
```

Then server-side realize that you have an array `$_POST['actions']`.

So you could do something like this:

```
if(is_array($_POST['actions']) && in_array("delete_account", $_POST['actions'])) {
   // process the delete
```

Side note: regarding S3 pricing, you do realize that they charge you one penny for *two thousand* POST requests right? I'm all for making code concise. But if it really complicates things for you, you may rethink this. S3 pricing for POST requests is ridiculously cheap.

Comment: ok, then how would you add the data values to send over to the PHP file?  Also, how would you recommend I refactor my PHP code? or should I just leave it as is?

Comment: @hyphen I just added to my answer, showing how you can look for these server-side now.

Comment: regarding the S3 pricing, I'm less concerned about that than about having the most efficient code possible, however, I do have a LOT of post requests for just one page.  If I ended up with a lot of users, I could see it growing pretty quickly.  Just want to think about this stuff early on when its relatively easy to change.

Comment: in the bit of PHP code you supplied, would I still need to use isset() like I did in my original PHP code, or does the fact that a POST variable is in an array negate the need for isset()?

Comment: @hyphen It's always a good idea to make sure the data is set and formatted the way you expect it to be. I just updated my answer. Use `is_array` instead of `isset` in this case.